# Correct formula for real GDP growth?

Tags: inflation, gdp

I have nominal GDP growth (%) and inflation (CPI price level growth, %). Which is the correct way to find real GDP growth (%)?

=((1+[nominal GDP growth%])/(1+[inflation%]))-1

or simply:

=[nominal GDP growth%] - [inflation%]

or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is more correct in discrete time and in general the second one is a good continuous time approximation.

We can decompose nominal GDP as the product of real GDP ($Y$) and the price level ($P$):
$$
GDP_t = P_t Y_t
$$

#### Discrete time

For a variable $X_t$ let $\Delta X = \dfrac{X_{t+1} - X_t}{X_t}= \dfrac{X_{t+1}}{X_t} - 1$ be the growth rate of $X$.

Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\Delta GDP + 1 &= \frac{GDP_{t+1}}{GDP_t}\\
&= \frac{P_{t+1}Y_{t+1}}{P_t Y_t},\\
&= \frac{P_{t+1}}{P_t} \frac{Y_{t+1}}{Y_t}\\
&= \left(1+ \Delta P_t\right)\left(1+ \Delta Y\right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore:
$$
1 + \Delta Y = \frac{1 + \Delta GDP}{1 + \Delta P}
$$
Which is the first formula that you have.

#### Continuous time approximation

Now if you would work in continuous time then growth rate of $X$ can be approximated by:
$$
\frac{d \ln(X(t))}{d t} = \frac{1}{X(t)} \dfrac{d X(t)}{d t} \approx \frac{X(t+1) - X(t)}{X_t}
$$
Then the rate of of GDP growth would be:
$$
\begin{align*}
\Delta GDP &= \frac{d \ln(GDP(t))}{d t} = \frac{d \ln(P(t))}{dt } + \frac{d \ln(Y(t))}{d t},\\
&= \Delta P + \Delta Y,\\
\end{align*}
$$
As such we can use the approximation:
$$
\Delta Y = \Delta GDP - \Delta P
$$